# MySQL LaunchDaemon on OS X Yosemite: Localhost connection fails

Tags: mysql, localhost, osx-yosemite

Starting with OS X 10.10 Yosemite, StartupItems are no longer supported. I have created a LaunchDaemon to automatically start the MySQL database on the server. So far it works, but I am unable to use "localhost" as connection parameter in a few tools (connection over socket is not intended to be used). Even 127.0.0.1 fails, but when I use the server's real ip address (192.168.x.y) the connection can be established.

LaunchDaemon code (we're using a non-standard installation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/data/my_app.mysql.debug.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/data/my_app.mysql.debug.log</string>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my_app.mysql</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
      <string>--socket=/tmp/my_app.mysql.sock</string>
      <string>--basedir=/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql</string>
      <string>--datadir=/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/data</string>
      <string>--port=3366</string>
      <string>--pid-file=/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/data/my_app.mysql.pid</string>
      <string>--log-error=/MY_APP_ROOT/mysql/data/my_app.mysql.err</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: problem is solved, there was a bug in the central code of our application framework... see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: found the problem in the central code of our application... sorry for posting here. The LaunchDaemon might be an example for those still looking for a solution on Yosemite, however.

Problem is solved.